# What is the temperature at the center of a square plate subjected to 4 different temperature at each edge?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

[image]

Dear all, assuming temperatures have all reached steady-state, is the center temperature will be exactly (T1+T2+T3+T4)/4 assuming this is a square plate with 4 different temperature at each edge?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?